# C# System.Commandline: How do I add an argument to a command so that I can pass a value to it?

Tags: c#, arguments, parameter-passing, .net-6.0, system.commandline

The following simple `Program.cs` expects a single argument for a defined root command:

```cs
using System.CommandLine;

var inputArgument = new Argument<string>(
  name: "--input", 
  description: "input any value and print it out");

var rootCommand = new RootCommand();
rootCommand.AddArgument(inputArgument);
rootCommand.SetHandler((inputArgumentValue) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{inputArgumentValue}");
}, inputArgument);

rootCommand.Invoke(args);
```

I would expect calling this with the following parameter: `--input "Hello World"` to print out *Hello World* in the shell. However I get the following error:

`Unrecognized command or argument 'Hello World'.`

When I replace the [Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.commandline.argument?view=system-commandline) class with the [Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.commandline.option.-ctor?view=system-commandline), it works as expected:

```cs
using System.CommandLine;

var inputArgument = new Option<string>(
  name: "--input", 
  description: "input any value and print it out");

var rootCommand = new RootCommand();
rootCommand.AddOption(inputArgument);
rootCommand.SetHandler((inputArgumentValue) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{inputArgumentValue}");
}, inputArgument);

rootCommand.Invoke(args);
```

**What did I misunderstand about the `Argument` class? Why can I not pass an argument with a value to it?**

---

I want to use the argument class instead of options due to its other properties. I am using .NET 6.0 and System.CommandLine version 2.0.0-beta4.22272.1

Comment: arguments are without `--` | `foo.exe input` - eg. `dotnet run` vs `dotnet run --arch x86` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run | `run` is an argument `--arch` is an option

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for your reply. I tried it out, makes no difference if I use `--` or not. Even if I define the name of the argument just `input`, then `input "Hello World"` does not work. I think regarding your example for `System.Commandline` and dotnet, `run` would not be an argument, it would be a [Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.commandline.command?view=system-commandline)

Comment: It can be either a command or an argument, the command line syntax is identical for both. but yeah, you are most likely correct dotnet will have `run` specified as command. this sample `foo.exe input "Hello World"` are 2 arguments first argument has value `input` second argument has value `Hello World`

Comment: see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS76u.png

Comment: @RandRandom _"`run` is an argument `--arch` is an option"_ - if I understand correctly `run` should be a `Command` in `System.CommandLine` terms.

Comment: @GuruStron - yeah, OP already pointed that out - my bad, though the syntax is identical so it could be either, though dotnet most likely used command

Comment: thanks for you replies guys, I understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Command-line syntax overview for `System.CommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax) docs.

It defines [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax#options) as:

> An option is a named parameter that can be passed to a command. The POSIX convention is to prefix the option name with two hyphens (`--`).

And [arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax#arguments) as:

> An argument is a value passed to an option or a command.

So basically argument is a nameless positional parameter passed to command or option, i.e. for your first snippet valid call would be:

```bash
appName "Hello World"
```

You can of course add 2 arguments:

```
var inputArgument = new Argument<string>(
    name: "input", 
    description: "input any value and print it out");
var inputArgument2 = new Argument<string>(
    name: "input2", 
    description: "input any value and print it out");

var rootCommand = new RootCommand();
rootCommand.AddArgument(inputArgument);
rootCommand.AddArgument(inputArgument2);
rootCommand.SetHandler((inputArgumentValue, inputArgumentValue2) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{inputArgumentValue} - {inputArgumentValue2}");
}, inputArgument, inputArgument2);
```

Then your `appName --input "Hello World"` invocation will result in handler getting 2 values `--input` for `inputArgumentValue` and `"Hello World"` for `inputArgumentValue2`.

But I would argue using `Option<string>` (the second snippet) should be more correct approach (also it will allow passing values delimited with `=`: `appName --input="Hello World"`).

Comment: I wouldn't use `--` in the names of arguments, it could imply that `--` has a meaning, and for all I know the only meaning of the argument name is in the help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFskd.png

Comment: @RandRandom agree, removed.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it. Thanks for the clear and precise answer.